# Azure Blob Storage - Copy an archived blob to an online tier

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy a blob that is archived to an online tier. For that I am using the 8.4.0 API version (from August 2019), and I have also tried using the CLI.

However I am getting always this error: **"This operation is no permitted on an archived blob."**

In this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-rehydration) is clear that azure allows to copy an archived blob to an online tier.

Anyone knows how this can be done in java?

I am using the only function I know to copy a blob in java:
`destinationBlob.startCopy(sourceBlob);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob) indicated :

> **Copying Archived Blob (version 2018-11-09 and newer)**
>
> An archived blob can be copied to a new blob within the same storage
>   account. This will still leave the initially archived blob as is. When
>   copying an archived blob as source the request must contain the header
>   x-ms-access-tier indicating the tier of the destination blob. The data
>   will be eventually copied to the destination blob.

Only API version after 2018-11-09 will support copying archived blobs. As you mentioned , you are using [Azure Storage Java SDK V8](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java/tree/legacy-master) which has been moved to and stopped updating on 2018-9-24. I assume that the reason that you got this error.

Anyway , you can follow [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob) and using REST API to copy archived files .

Comment: Hi @toliveira , any further assistance needed ?